# scipy.io.wavfile.write no sound

Tags: python, scipy

I want to write a signal in a .wav file, but when I do this using
scipy.io.wavfile.write it just create me a .wav without sound.
The .wav  has the good length but there is no sound.
I looked for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find help.
My code below :

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype(np.int32)
sig = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=dt, count=-1, sep='')
sp.io.wavfile.write('sound.wav', int(fS), sig)
```

As a test, I also did a little function :

```
def write_wav_sin(name,fs,f):
    x = np.linspace(0,10,10*fs)
    dt = np.dtype(np.float32)
    sig = np.sin(2*math.pi*f*x, dtype=dt)
    print(type(sig[0]))
    sp.io.wavfile.write(name, fs, sig) 
    plt.plot(x,sig)
```

With this test  it works, but with my other code it doesn't work

Someone knows why I have this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the range of values in `sig` by printing `sig.min()` and `sig.max()`.  The values are not scaled by `wavfile.write`, so it might be that you have a file with values so low that you can't hear them.

Try scaling up the 32 bit integer values, or writing the data as normalized 32 bit floating point.  For example, this converts `sig` to 32 bit floating point values in the range [-1, 1] before saving it:

```
m = np.max(np.abs(sig))
sigf32 = (sig/m).astype(np.float32)
sp.io.wavfile.write('sound.wav', int(fS), sigf32)
```

Comment: Hi @warren, with your scaling it works way better, there is not artifacts/noise anymore, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a commented example on how to generate a basic wave file with a set duration, frequency, volume and number of samples. Utilizing [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and Python's [`wave`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.writeframes) library.

```
import numpy as ny
import struct
import wave


class SoundFile:
   def  __init__(self, signal):
       # https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/wave.html#wave.open
       self.file = wave.open('test.wav', 'wb')
       self.signal = signal
       self.sr = 44100

   def write(self):
       # https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.setparams
       self.file.setparams( ( 1, 2, self.sr, 44100 * 4, 'NONE', 'noncompressed' ) )
       # https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write.writeframes
       self.file.writeframes( self.signal )
       self.file.close()

# signal settings
duration = 4 # duration in Seconds
samplerate = 44100 # Hz (frequency) 
samples = duration * samplerate # aka samples per second
frequency = 440 # Hz
period = samplerate / float( frequency ) # of samples
omega = ny.pi * 2 / period # calculate omega (angular frequency)
volume = 16384 # 16384 is the volume measure (max is 32768)

# create sin wave
xaxis = ny.arange( samples, dtype = ny.float )
ydata = volume * ny.sin( xaxis * omega )

# fill blanks
signal = ny.resize( ydata, ( samples, ) )

#create sound file
f = SoundFile( signal )
f.write()

print( 'sound file created' )
```

Did my best to comment, update, and modify [this](http://codingmess.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-make-simple-wav-file-with-python.html) source by a random blogger.

Comment: Hi @Noah , thank you for your answer. Do this code works for you ? I tried this code and it doesn't works because of the line :  ssignal = ''.join( ( wave.struct.pack( 'h', item ) for item in signal ) )   struct.error: required argument is not an integer.

Comment: @AntoineV I'm sorry about that. I tested using an older version of Python. I've updated the original post with working code. `struct.pack` is no longer needed in later versions of NumPy/Python; resizing the array and then creating a new instance of SoundFile (w/o packing) gives the out put we want. Enjoy! Any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I divided all  my signal to have an amplitude max way more little ( my signal had sometimes an amplitude of 500000, to write it in a Wav I divided it by 250000).

With that trick I can listen to the sound but there is something weird, like additionnal artifacts/noise ( I compared it to a .wav obtained with  matlab , with the same file )

the code I used is :

```
    import scipy as sp
    import numpy as np
    dt = np.dtype(np.int32)
    sig = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=dt, count=-1, sep='')
    sp.io.wavfile.write('sound.wav', int(fS), sig/250000)
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer.